# Unity is returning a null object when deployed to server but not on local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container, iis-8.5

### Issue

The below code runs fine on my local machine, but once I've deployed it `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>()` returns null, leading to this:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   xxxx.API.Providers.<GrantResourceOwnerCredentials>d__2.MoveNext() in
   D:\xxxx\xxxx.API\Providers\ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs:36
```

when `userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password)` is called. Please advise what my next steps should be? I'm not even sure where to start looking beyond server logs.

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roleManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationRoleManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
        var userRoles = user.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId);

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        oAuthIdentity.AddClaims(roleManager.Roles.Where(r => userRoles.Any(ur => ur == r.Id))
            .Select(r => r.Claims).ToList()
            .Select(c => new Claim("RoleClaims", c.ToString())));

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

### Update

Had a play around with my deploy and have discovered the issue does not arise when I deploy the API to a separate folder from the matching website I'm hosting (My API and website are two separate projects).

So when I deploy the website to xxxx and API to xxxx/API the above issue occurs.

When I deploy the website to xxxx and API to xxxxAPI the above issue does not occur.

The hosting paths on my local machine mirror that of the remote so I presume this is a configuration issue. Does this indicate further to anybody what the problem might be?